# Error while Linking Framework SDKs on Xamarin. "Cant resolve the reference...."

Tags: ios, xamarin, linker-errors

I am trying to compile my code using the "Link Framework SDKs Only" option, since I am trying to make my code lighter. Whenever I try with "Dont link", the code compiles without a problem, but once I choose the "Link Framework SDKs Only" option an error pops up.

The VS version is 16.10.3 and Xcode is 12.3
Additionally, I am using the following nuggets and references:
-Entity Framework
-Plugin.FacebookClient
-Plugin.NFC
-Plugin.PushNotification-updated
-Rg.Plugins.Popup
-SkiaSharp.Views.Forms
-sqlite-net-pcl
-System
-System.Core
-System.Data.Services.Client
-System.Numerics
-System.Numerics.Vectors
-System.Xml
-Xam.Plugin.Badge
-Xam.Plugin.Connectivity
-Xam.Plugin.Media
-Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle
-Xam.Plugins.Settings
-Xamarin.Auth
-Xamarin.Essentials
-Xamarin.Forms
-Xamarin.Forms.InputKit
-Xamarin.Forms.OpenWhatsApp
-Xamarin.iOS
-ZXing.Net.Mobile

I would like to know if anybody has encountered a similar error, or knows how to solve this. The image below shows the exact error that´s popping up

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1uVm.jpg)

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: Could you provide more details about this issue? What is the version of the VS and Xcode?

Comment: Hello @WendyZang-MSFT
I added some more information to the original post, as well as the VS and Xcode versions! Thanks for your help

Comment: It seems you use a third-party nuget. Try to create a new project  to test. You could try to skip the assemblies to avoid. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos#skipping-assemblies